# Tratamiento de datos para tener 3 decimales y no quite el cero

Tags: c#, decimal

Hola hola tengo una aplicacion en C# y necesito que para capturar en AS400 una cantidad esta tenga 3 decimales, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```cs
double galones = Gallons / Balance; 
galones = Math.Round(galones, 3);
```

Necesito que alguien me ayude para hacer tratamiento de datos, para cuando me salga 0.12 que se agregue otro 0 y asi tener 3 decimales, porque cuando el tercer decimal o segundo son 0 se borran y yo quiero mantener el decimal con 3

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene un error de concepto.. los 0 a la derecha no se guardan ni en la base de datos ni en ningun lado.. vos donde queres que se vean los 3 decimales? al mostrarlo por pantalla??? si es asi, con un string.format te sobra....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez tengas el resultado numerico al que deseas agregarle los ceros a la derecha del punto decimal, debes convertirlo a string, utilizando 'ToString("fX")', en el que la "X" puedes reemplazarla por la cantidad de digitos que deseas despues del punto decimal. Ejemplo:

```
double galones = 0.12;
string galonesConCeros = galones.ToString("f5");
Console.WriteLine(galonesConCeros);
//salida: 0.12000
```

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias. Es mi primer aporte en el sitio.